# not able to extract content from span using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to extract the product code from the site http://www.firstcry.com/morisons-baby-dreams/morisons-baby-dreams-soother-nipple/234227/product-detail using x-path:

```
     item['pcode'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('//*[@id="disp_proid"]/text()').extract()).strip()
```

But I'm getting the null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using javascript to fill in the `span`.

Use this:

```
item['pcode'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hid_ProductID"]/@value').extract()).strip()
```

Comment: Hey thanks. It worked
can you please tell me how to extract the image url also? I'm trying this:

       item['pimg'] = ' '.join(hxs.select('/html/body/div[2]/img/@src').extract()).strip()